Building App Failed with "Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles"
Hello Fastlane community,
I'm trying to implement an iOS build and upload a App Store in a CI/CD workflow using GitHub Actions with Fastlane, but I can't pass the build step. I'm a first time Fastlane user, so maybe I'm failing in something very basic.
When the process reaches the build step, it throws the error "No profiles for '' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching ''. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'App' from project 'App')".
The application is an Ionic application and the Xcode project was generated using Ionic (ionic capacitor add ios) also the generated project was not modified.
Since we are trying implement a CI/CD workflow, I need to configure the project using the Fastfile instead of Xcode GUI.
We are using match to generate the certificates, do I need to load the in any way for xcodebuild to use them?
Configuration files and logs:
Action log: https://pastebin.com/zHrYg9Lf Fastfile: https://pastebin.com/3CUY2gej Matchfile: https://pastebin.com/yy0q2eG3 Gemfile: https://pastebin.com/deAEhdVb Pluginfile: https://pastebin.com/rb2z7LSJ
Before adding "update_project_team" to the Fastfile (It is attached), it was throwing the error "Signing for "App" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'App' from project 'App')"
Adding disable_automatic_code_signing to the Fastfile, throws the error: "App" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'App' from project 'App')"

The compilation was successfull after disabling automatic code signing (adding disable_automatic_code_signing before match) and replacing update_project_provisioning with update_code_signing_settings.
Looks like match by itself does not update the project to use the profile it generates (makes sense) and you need to load it manually.
